# Отобразить сожержимое списка Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

На данном моменте у меня есть некая база данных(Firebase Realtime Database), которая содержит в себе  имя и значение.
Данный список я отображаю у себя в `recyclerView`. 
И сейчас хотелось бы чтобы по нажатию на тот или иной элемент списка открывался контент для конкретного элемента.

Так понимаю сначала мне нужно поменять структуру самой бд загрузив некий .json файл со своей структурой и лишь потом в него заливать данные пункты?
Уверен что многие сталкивались с данным вопросам, но увы пока ничего подобного не нахожу. Любому совету, tutorial'у как отобразить содержимое элемента списка буду рад.

Кусок кода где получаю данный из БД:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupViews()
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    val childEventListener = object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            val value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
            value?.let { mTopWords.add(it) }

            val key = dataSnapshot.key
            key?.let { mKeys.add(it) }
            adapter.data = mTopWords
        }

        override fun onChildChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            val value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
            val key = dataSnapshot.key
            val index: Int = mKeys.indexOf(key)
            value?.let { mTopWords.set(index, it) }
        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        }

        override fun onChildMoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {

        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

        }
    }
    mDatabase?.addChildEventListener(childEventListener)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

создай базу данных, например:

```
public class UserData {

    String userId;
    String userName;

    public UserData () {
    }

    public ClientData(long userId, String userName) {
        this.userId= userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

Затем в классе где ты бежишь по FireBase создай ArrayList:

```
   ArrayList<UserData > arrayListUsers;
```

и в методе где ты по одному вытаскиваешь юзеров вотни это:

```
  arrayListUsers.add(new UserData(id, name));
```

а готовый лист отправляй в **recyclerView** ,само сабой через адаптер. И в этом адаптере уже играешься как хочешь.

я бы так сделал. Надеюсь тебе это поможет.

Прошу прощения, что не на kotlin а на java, пока надобностит нет за kotlin браться